# How to check if the value of a generic type is the zero value?

Tags: go, generics

The generics proposal has a [section](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#the-zero-value) on how to return the zero value of a type parameter, but it does not mention how to check if a value of a parametrized type is the zero value.

The only way I can think of is to use `reflect.ValueOf(...).IsZero()`, is there an alternative?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the equal operator with the `*new(T)` idiom. The constraint of the generic param must be, or embed, `comparable` to support the equality operator, or specify a type set of comparable types:

```
func IsZero[T comparable](v T) bool {
    return v == *new(T)
}
```

If you can’t constrain `T` to `comparable` then you’re left with reflection. Zombo’s suggestion to address the variable like this:

```
reflect.ValueOf(&v).Elem().IsZero()
```

is superior to simply `reflect.ValueOf(v).IsZero()` because `ValueOf` takes an `interface{}` argument and if `v` just happens to be an interface you would loose that information. I don’t think that with generics you will often instantiate a function with an interface but it’s worth knowing. So:

```
    func IsZero[T any](v T) bool {
        return reflect.ValueOf(&v).Elem().IsZero()
    }
```

Using a variable of type `T` and using that in the comparison also works. It is more readable than `*new(T)`, but it requires an additional `var` declaration. The operands still must be comparable:

```
func IsZero[T comparable](v T) bool {
    var zero T
    return v == zero
}
```

If you are concerned about the performance of reflection, it is indeed slightly worse than pure comparable generics:

```
go1.18rc1 test -v -bench=. -benchmem
goos: darwin
goarch: arm64
pkg: example.com
BenchmarkGenerics-10        1000000000      0.3295 ns/op     0 B/op   0 allocs/op
BenchmarkReflection-10      94129023        12.26 ns/op      8 B/op   1 allocs/op
```

If you know you won't instantiate the reflect-based function with an interface, you can simplify the code to `reflect.ValueOf(v).IsZero()` which gives a minor improvement:

```
go1.18rc1 test -v -bench=. -benchmem
goos: darwin
goarch: arm64
pkg: example.com
BenchmarkGenerics-10          1000000000    0.3295 ns/op     0 B/op   0 allocs/op
BenchmarkReflection-10        94129023      12.26 ns/op      8 B/op   1 allocs/op
BenchmarkReflectionNoAddr-10  100000000     11.41 ns/op      8 B/op   0 allocs/op
```

Answer (score 3):

If the type is comparable, then compare the value to a variable set to the zero value of the type.

```golang
var zero T
isZero := v == zero
```

Use the reflect package if the type is not comparable:

```golang
isZero := reflect.ValueOf(&v).Elem().IsZero()
```